# Default font size

Tags: software-center

So I downloaded Advanced Settings from the Ubuntu Software center and I was playing around with the font sizes when it lagged and it got stuck at the largest font size.  So, I can't open any programs such as Advanced Settings anymore because the fonts too big, and I need to find a way to default the font or make it smaller so I can use the computer again.  I do have access to the terminal - but thats about it.

Thanks to any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct solution but you could open another terminal, do 'sudo adduser' and login with that user after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the login screen , but then login using the Console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and not the login screen, then open the file ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/interface/%gconf.xml for example with nano:

```
nano ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/interface/%gconf.xml
```

Then you should see the font settings somewhere. Just edit the numbers (you'll know which ones are for the size) and don't remove any "<" or ">" or anything similar!

You can also just reset the settings by deleting the settings file:

```
rm ~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/interface/%gconf.xml
```

After editing or deleting the file, use Alt+F7 to get back to the login screen, log in normally and the font should be normal again.